# PHP - MYSQL - insert on duplicate key AND(?)

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to connect the duplicate key to another statement.
I just picked some integers `(4=4)` for the example. In the actuall code I am trying to compare two dates and only if the date in the database row is bigger than the php generated date AND duplicated key it should update `unj` to `7`.

from this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mutable (hid, xsn, unj, for, datetime)
VALUES ('$hid', '$xsn', '$unj', '$for', now()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE unj=7";
```

to this:

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO mutable (hid, xsn, unj, for, datetime)
VALUES ('$hid', '$xsn', '$unj', '$for', now()) ON 4=4 AND DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE unj=7";
```

( **ON 4=4 AND** ) added.

But this is not working. Is there any way to archive this?

Thank you.

**edit**: I know I could archive this with using SELECT and then INPUT or UPDATE but I need more efficient code.

Comment: Have you searched how to compare dates in SQL?

Comment: I don't think you can do anything like this; `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is specific syntax.  What is your goal?

Comment: @JustinWood This is not about dates but about the SQL statement and how to use `on duplicate key` with another value.I replaced the dates with `4=4` to simplify the question.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Basically I have a table where votes are saved. The user has the option to change his vote. (I know I could archive this with using SELECT and then INPUT or UPDATE) but this seems inefficient. BUT the user can only change his vote to a specific date which is saved in the db entry.

Comment: I don't know if I am correct. But you want to allow the user to change its vote only before a certain date. And if this date is expired you want to prohibit the user from changing his vote. If this is the case I would recommend doing this with PHP code. A simple if statement would do.

Comment: @Mr.Radical The dates are saved in the database for each user.

Comment: @Kallewallex are the users logged in when they cast their votes? If so you could first do a query where you retrieve the date for the specific user and then do a if statement to decide if the user is allowed to change its vote.

Comment: @Mr.Radical Yes, they are. But this is for a mobile application. I want to keep the data passed to the user low. Second, there are a lot of vote entries and end-dates for each users (1000+).

Comment: Oke, I see @Bill Karwin has solved the problem. Good job. And if its is to save data traffic for the users this is better.

Comment: @Mr.Radical Maybe you can help me anyway. I am trying to replace the date time in the if clausal with an datetime column from another table. like this `IF(mutable2x.datetime > VALUES(datetime), 7, unj)` but of course this does not work. Do you have a idea?

Comment: @Kallewallex I have never done this, but it might work. Try a normal select query inside the if statement. Like so: IF((SELECT mutable2x.datetime FROM mutable2x) > VALUES(datetime), 7, unj) with the brackets.

Comment: @Mr.Radical Seemed like a good Idea. At first it was throwing an 1242 mysql error at my face, then I added an WHERE clausal and it didn't threw any error and triggered my success function but it did not chang the value to `7`, however... I am sure this is the right path. Gonna try a few things. Thank you very much Mr. Radical :)

Comment: @Mr.Radical The entry I used was incomplete, there was no matching entry in mutable2x, after choosing an other entry it worked with `IF((SELECT mutable2x.datetime FROM mutable2x WHERE mutable2x.hid = $hid) > VALUES(datetime), 7, uni)` Thank you very much. I am tired. 3:44am already. Good night.

Comment: @Kallewallex great to hear that you solved your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO mutable (hid, xsn, unj, `for`, datetime)
VALUES ('$hid', '$xsn', '$unj', '$for', now()) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE unj = IF(datetime > VALUES(datetime), 7, unj)
```

I tested this and it works.

The `VALUES(datetime)` refers to the value you *tried* to insert into the `datetime` column. It's a convenient way to repeat the value in your `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause without having to write it twice in the query.

If the condition in `IF()` returns false, then the default is to set `unj = unj` which means a no-op.

PS: `for` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html), so it needs to be delimited. It would be simpler to avoid that column name.

Comment: Beautiful. It works. I knew there was a more efficient way than using SEL+INS/UPD.
**Thank you very much.** PS: My column isn't named "for" I just made all these values and vars up because I am unsure about my contract and the information I am allowed to pass on.

Comment: Is there any way to replace the date (`datetime`) with datetime from another table? like `IF(mutable2x.datetime > VALUES(datetime), 7, uni)`

Comment: @Kallewallex, you might be able to use a scalar subquery, but I haven't tested that. And it would at least work counter to your goal of making an efficient query. :-)

Comment: I am using `IF((SELECT mutable2x.datetime FROM mutable2x WHERE mutable2x.hid = $hid) > VALUES(datetime), 7, unj)` in my `INSERT` query because the date is stored in another table. **I have no Idea how else to archive this**. And it is still more efficient then using SELECT and then INSERT or UPDATE isn't it?

Comment: Don't count on it being "more efficient" just because one SQL statement is fewer than two SQL statements. You have to measure to be sure. You don't want to be like the boy in the Shel Silverstein poem who traded his two quarters for three dimes, and feels like he came out ahead because three is more than two!

Comment: Haha. Well, I don't have enough experience in this to tell if it would be more efficient and I don't know how to measure it. But the alternative would be a SELECT statement and if it returns a row do UPDATE and if it does not return a row do INSERT. How do I find out what is more efficient?